# Expecto: log individual test statuses

Tags: .net, build, f#, expecto

I've got a test that occasionally flakes and crashes my test process. However, I can't figure out which test is causing the failure. The only output I get is

[image: Console output]

How can I get test results to log as they happen so I can find the failing test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is more a dotnet cli question, since I'm running tests via `dotnet test` and the [YoloDev.Expecto.TestSdk adapter](https://github.com/YoloDev/YoloDev.Expecto.TestSdk).

The answer is to [add a simple logger argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61087246/when-running-dotnet-test-show-output-of-the-dotnet-vstest-output-sink)

```
dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=detailed"
```

Comment: Also may be useful to use dedicated helpers for finding failing test with `blame*` family of arguments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#arguments